# VBA to parse data into separate worksheets by a column value AND have column headers on each sheet

Tags: vba, excel

'Please help me get the column headers into all worksheets.  Thanks!

```
'SAMPLE CODE FROM THIS SITE
'doesn't add column headers to 3+worksheets

Sub SplitData()

    Dim MyFiles As String
    MyFiles = Dir("C:\Users\jkirby\Desktop\extracted data\*.xlsb")
    Do While MyFiles <> ""
      Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\jkirby\Desktop\extracted data\" & MyFiles

      'deactivate windows security nag
      Application.DisplayAlerts = False

      Dim DataMarkers(), Names As Range, name As Range, n As Long, i As Long

      Set Names = Range("F2:F" & Range("a1").End(xlDown).Row)
      n = 0

      For Each name In Names
        If name.Offset(1, 0) <> name Then
            ReDim Preserve DataMarkers(n)
            DataMarkers(n) = name.Row
            Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).name = name
            n = n + 1
        End If
      Next name

      For i = 0 To UBound(DataMarkers)
        If i = 0 Then
            Worksheets(1).Range("A1:ay" & DataMarkers(i)).Copy _
                          Destination:=Worksheets(i + 2).Range("a1")
        Else
            'won't work because it's not copying column headers
            Worksheets(1).Range("A" & (DataMarkers(i - 1) + 1) & _
                               ":AY" & DataMarkers(i)).Copy _
                    Destination:=Worksheets(i + 2).Range("a1")

        End If
      Next i

      'save as binary (for compression and formatting)
      ActiveWorkbook.saveAs Filename:=Left(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, Len(ActiveWorkbook.FullName) - 4) & ".xlsb", FileFormat:=xlExcel12

      'reactivate windows security nag
      Application.DisplayAlerts = True

      'close the file we just worked on
      ActiveWorkbook.Close

      'Let's do it again until they are all done
      MyFiles = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You may want to change this:

```
    'won't work because it's not copying column headers
    Worksheets(1).Range("A" & (DataMarkers(i - 1) + 1) & _
                       ":AY" & DataMarkers(i)).Copy _
            Destination:=Worksheets(i + 2).Range("a1")
```

into this:

```
    'won't work because it's not copying column headers
    Worksheets(1).Range("A" & (DataMarkers(i + 1 - 1) + 1) & _
                       ":AY" & DataMarkers(i)).Copy _
            Destination:=Worksheets(i + 2).Range("a1")
```

Because within the second condition, i can be 1, so DataMarkers(1-1) returns 0, and not columns in Excel start at 0

Additionally, **I wouldn't recommend using Name or Names as range or else variable types since these are VBA reserved keywords for worksheet or workbook range names**.

Cheers,

Pascal

http://multiskillz.tekcities.com